# While updating a form how to show the textarea value in ActiveForm yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

While updating a form having textarea as input box, I am unable to show the value in textarea.  Can anybody help me to find out the problem?

`$form->field($model, 'registered_address_line1')->textarea(['rows' => 2, $seller->registered_address_line1])`

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 'trying to get textarea value'?

Comment: What i mean to say that at the time of update a from I have to populate the text area field value which shows an error.....I think language shouldn't be the barrier to vote down a question. It demoralizes a person's effort.

Comment: If you know that your english is limited, it is wise to check the question before posting, because it was very unclear what you were asking. I didn't give you the downvote btw, but do understand why other users would.

Comment: Is it still unclear to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set the value in the textarea, you need to set the value of that property in the model. In your case:

```
$model->registered_address_line1 = $seller->registered_address_line1;
$form->field($model, 'registered_address_line1')->textarea(['rows' => 2]);
```